# Multiple Steps Form with Specific Input Values

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a Multi Steps Form.

Each step has just one Input Field and a NEXT button
I want to set it, so that a field is only valid when you put a specific text.

So for example, The first part of the form has one input field for NAME... I want it to only accept the name JOHN before it goes to the next step, if not it should give an error alert.

Kindly help with whatever code i need to change or add.

I apologise for any form of bad english. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my html code;

```
<form>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">First Name:
    <p><input  placeholder="First Name..." ></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Last Name:
    <p><input  placeholder="Last Name..." ></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." ></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" ">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You will want to track all inputs in all the forms and you might want a "Back" button. I suggest using [PHP session handling](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: Voting to close since the question is *too broad. "Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question."*

Comment: Whats the point of a form if it will only accept one specific answer? Guessing game or something? Anyways, HTML5 inputs can help you with restricting what can be written inside the inputs. The quick and dirty way is to comparing the current input value with what you want on click. If right answer, load the next question, else error.

Comment: @Shilly .... Exactly what you said... If right answer, load the next question, else error.

Comment: If you;re going to script it, it's rather easy no? Get the element using your favourite selector. If element.id === 'name', requested_answer = 'JOHN'. If requested_answer === element.value, load next question. Else throw new error. But since there's no structure at all explaining how you will be loading the new questions and such, it's hard to provide code that will actually work.

Comment: @Shilly.. Am really liking your suggestions... Since you understand my question well. Can you please give a sample multi step question and answer code.

Comment: Are you going to submit the form to the server between each step and will you generate a new page with PHP to show the next question? Or are you going to have the entire form on one page, do everything client side and only send the form to php once all questions have been answered?

Comment: @Shilly Questions should be on one page... But you can only be abe to view the next question if the previous one is answered correctly...

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $("#nextBtn").click(function(){
            var tab = $(".tab:not(.hidden)");
            var input = tab.find("input");
            var checks = {
                "firstname": "John",
                "lastname": "Smith",
                "email": "j.smith@example.com"
            };
            if(input.val() == checks[input.attr("name")]){
                tab.addClass("hidden");
                if(tab.next().length) {
                    tab.next().removeClass("hidden");
                }else{
                    //submit form
                }
            }else{
                alert("wrong input");
            }

        });
```

```css
 .hidden{
      display:none!important;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
      <div class="tab">First Name:
        <p><input name="firstname" placeholder="First Name..." ></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab hidden">Last Name:
        <p><input name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name..." ></p>
      </div>
      <div class="tab hidden">Contact Info:
        <p><input name="email" placeholder="E-mail..." ></p>
      </div>
      <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button" id="nextBtn" ">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Am sorry... This does not work... It doesnt go to the next question.. Lastname

Comment: The disadvantage is that you can easily look into the client-side script to find the correct answer.